# undefined reference to `vtable in custom lib created with cmake

Tags: cmake, qt5

I'm getting the error: lib/libhrlLib.so: undefined reference to `hrlQseqDev::waiting(bool, int)' and some more ...
I'm trying to build my project with cmake (3.7.2) instead of with qmake (Qt5)

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(${TARGET_NAME})

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE FALSE)

macro(NAMELIST erg in)
    set(os "")
    set(srcs ${in})
    separate_arguments(srcs)
    foreach(is ${srcs})
        set(os ${os} ${is})
    endforeach(is)
    set(${erg} ${os})
endmacro(NAMELIST)

macro(FINDMODULES erg in)
    set(os "")
    set(srcs ${in})
    separate_arguments(srcs)
    foreach(is ${srcs})
        find_package(Qt5${is} REQUIRED)
        set(os ${os} Qt5::${is})
    endforeach(is)
    set(${erg} ${os})
endmacro(FINDMODULES)

NAMELIST(SRCS ${TARGET_SRCS})
FINDMODULES(QLIBS ${QMODULES})

if(INC_PATH)
    NAMELIST(INCS ${INC_PATH})
    set(INCLUDES ${INCS})
endif(INC_PATH)

if(TARGET_EXTLIBS)
    NAMELIST(EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} "${TARGET_EXTLIBS}")
endif(TARGET_EXTLIBS)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

include_directories(${INCLUDES})

if(BUILD_LIB)
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS "-shared")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS "-shared")

    add_library(${TARGET_NAME} SHARED ${SRCS})
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${QLIBS} ${EXTRA_LIBS})
    set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY VERSION "1.0.0")
    set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY SOVERSION 1 )
    install(TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
    install(TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME} LIBRARY DESTINATION lib NAMELINK_ONLY)
else()
    if(USE_LIB_PATH)
        add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRCS})
        target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} -L${OUT_PATH}/lib lib${USE_LIB}.so.1
            ${QLIBS} ${EXTRA_LIBS})
    else()
        add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${SRCS})
        target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${QLIBS} ${EXTRA_LIBS})
    endif(USE_LIB_PATH)
    install(TARGETS ${TARGET_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
endif(BUILD_LIB)
```

The shared library is built with:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DINC_PATH:STRING="some includes" -DTARGET_EXTLIBS:STRING="sys libs" -DTARGET_NAME:STRING=LibName -DBUILD_LIB:BOOL=1 -DTARGET_SRCS:STRING="cpp- and c-file" -DQMODULES:STRING="Core Gui Widgets PrintSupport" -DOUT_PATH:STRING=InstallPath .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=InstallPath >> /dev/null
```

When I try to build a program against this shared library with:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DINC_PATH:STRING="some includes" -DTARGET_EXTLIBS:STRING="sys libs" -DTARGET_NAME:STRING=ProgName -DBUILD_LIB:BOOL=0 -DTARGET_SRCS:STRING="cpp-file" -DQMODULES:STRING="Core Gui Widgets PrintSupport" -DOUT_PATH=InstallPath -DUSE_LIB:STRING="LibName" -DUSE_LIB_PATH:STRING="BuildPath of LibName" .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=InstallPath >> /dev/null
```

I get the error 'lib/libhrlLib.so: undefined reference to ...'.
I do not get this error when the library was built with qmake.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you verified with the nm utility, that the library contains that symbol?

Comment: I have verified this, as many other symbols. Example my own Widget .enderArea -> nm -D ../../../lib/libhrlLib.so.1.0.0 | grep 'RenderArea' ->                         
 ... 0000000000028d12 T _ZN10RenderArea13keyPressEventEP9QKeyEvent
0000000000028cd2 T _ZN10RenderArea14mouseMoveEventEP11QMouseEvent
0000000000028e9e T _ZN10RenderArea15keyReleaseEventEP9QKeyEvent
0000000000028556 T _ZN10RenderArea15mousePressEventEP11QMouseEvent
0000000000027c3a T _ZN10RenderAreaC1EP7QWidget
0000000000027c3a T _ZN10RenderAreaC2EP7QWidget
                 U _ZTV10RenderArea

Comment: And from build the error: ... undefined reference to `vtable for RenderArea'